# Анализ файла трассировки Oracle

Tags: oracle, трассировка

Нужна помощь в анализе трассировочных файлов.
Есть 2 БД Oracle 11g прод и предпрод, идентичны по железу и данным.  Один и тот же пакет, для расчета витрин данных на прод базе среде  выполняется за 1 час, на предпрод за 32 минуты. DBA утверждают, что разбежка возникает из-за логирования и репликации на проде (на предпроде отключены). Снял трассу по самой "тяжёлой" процедуре, прогнал через TKPROF:

Прод:

```
call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse        1      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Execute      1    336.45    2036.89    1394030   14622771       2375     2255256
Fetch        0      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total        2    336.45    2036.89    1394030   14622771       2375     2255256

Elapsed times include waiting on following events:
  Event waited on                             Times   Max. Wait  Total Waited
  ----------------------------------------   Waited  ----------  ------------
  Disk file operations I/O                       34        0.00          0.00
  db file sequential read                    127693        0.39        746.45
  latch: row cache objects                        1        0.00          0.00
  PX Deq: Join ACK                                4        0.00          0.00
  PX Deq Credit: send blkd                        1        0.00          0.00
  PX qref latch                                   1        0.00          0.00
  PX Deq Credit: free buffer                      3        0.00          0.00
  PX Deq: Parse Reply                             4        2.16          2.16
  PX Deq: Execute Reply                          16        0.01          0.01
  db file scattered read                       7202        0.15        101.93
  direct path read temp                       76238        0.16        852.81
  direct path write temp                       5045        0.05          1.59
  db file parallel read                           1        0.03          0.03
  PX Deq Credit: need buffer                      7        0.00          0.00
  reliable message                                1        0.00          0.00
  enq: CR - block range reuse ckpt                1        0.01          0.01
  PX Deq: Signal ACK RSG                          4        0.00          0.00
********************************************************************************
```

Предпрод:

```
call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse        1      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Execute      1    318.83    1363.52    1965651   14911127       6754     2255256
Fetch        0      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total        2    318.84    1363.53    1965651   14911127       6754     2255256

Elapsed times include waiting on following events:
  Event waited on                             Times   Max. Wait  Total Waited
  ----------------------------------------   Waited  ----------  ------------
  db file sequential read                    478133        0.29        991.26
  Disk file operations I/O                       16        0.00          0.00
  PX Deq: Join ACK                                4        0.00          0.00
  PX Deq Credit: send blkd                        2        0.00          0.00
  PX Deq Credit: need buffer                      4        0.02          0.02
  PX Deq: Parse Reply                             4        1.81          1.82
  PX Deq: Execute Reply                          16        0.00          0.01
  db file scattered read                       6864        0.10         22.23
  direct path write temp                      71579        0.05         45.86
  local write wait                             5856        0.00          2.77
  direct path read temp                       96801        0.00          2.57
  log file switch (private strand flush incomplete)
                                                  1        0.00          0.00
  db file parallel read                           1        0.00          0.00
  log file switch completion                      3        0.00          0.01
  reliable message                                4        0.00          0.00
  enq: CR - block range reuse ckpt                1        0.00          0.00
  PX Deq: Signal ACK RSG                          4        0.00          0.00
********************************************************************************
```

Процессорное время выполнения +/- совпадает, а вот фактическое довольно существенно разнится, на проде + 11 минут. Вижу что проблема в ожиданиях в частности "direct path read temp ". Подскажите в какую сторону копать, чтобы понять источник и причину возникновения этих ожиданий.

P.S.
`WAIT #139739871601368: nam='db file sequential read' ela= 178 file#=470 block#=1333217 blocks=1 obj#=25174871 tim=1580887605427410`

`tim=1580887605427410` - это в каких единицах измерения?

Comment: tim это явно текущее время в микросекундах (с 1970 года), как раз 2020-02-05 10:26:45.4274 выходит

Comment: И да, если на одной машине диск другими запросами (от пользователей, репликацией, логированием) не загружен, а на другой загружен - то разница во времени выполнения может быть огромной. Лучше копать в других направлениях - оптимизация запросов, изменение конфигурации железа и разнесение нагрузки на разные диски